# How to insert value to database based on its row after fetch?

Tags: php, pdo

I fetch data from database using PDO

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 echo "
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Submit url</td>
    <td><input type="text"><input type="submit"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 ";
}
```

And I want to insert a value to the database based on its row. How can I do that? Thank you for the answer...

Comment: you can use unique id and `update/insert` with `ajax/post/get`

Answer (score 1):

You mean update

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET name=?, surname=?, sex=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$name, $surname, $sex, $id]);
```